# New to Python, what's wrong with my code? How do I make the game store the gold value, and start a new iteration until user quits?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I know this probably isn't even close, but I'm trying to create a dice rolling game, where if you roll a certain number, it adds to another variable, like a currency in a game.  I keep getting an invalid syntax error on my elif statement about adding gold.

```
import random 

num = random.randint(1, 7)

def dice_roll():

    gold = 0
    if num == 2:
        gold = (gold + 2)
        gold = gold
        print (gold)
        print ('You Win!')
    else:
        print ('Loser')

dice_roll()
```

Comment: Could you please copy-paste the exact error message to the question. It makes it easier to tell what is wrong. Also, there doesn't seem to be any elif statement in the code you've shown.

Comment: Not related to your question but I have to ask - what exactly is the intention of `gold = gold`.

Comment: To update the value of gold, from it's current value, and add 2

Comment: That is already accomplished by `gold = gold + 2`. Doing `gold = gold` does nothing.

Comment: JJJ sorry didn't see your comment till now, I actually figured out my original question, but then had another so edited question, must've forgot to take out the elif.

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped your code in a tiny class, and made a couple changes. I am keeping a global counter for the amount of gold the user has accumulated

```
import random

class RollGame:

    def __init__(self, gold_increment=2):
        self.accumulated_gold = 0
        self.gold_increment = gold_increment

    def dice_roll(self):
        num = random.randint(1, 7)

        if num == 2:
            self.accumulated_gold = self.accumulated_gold + self.gold_increment
            print 'Accumulated Gold: {}'.format(self.accumulated_gold)
            print ('You Win!')
        else:
            print ('Loser')

    def play(self):

        while True:
            choice = raw_input('play? (Y/N)  ')

            if choice in ['y', 'Y']:
                self.dice_roll()

game = RollGame()
game.play()

game_2 = RollGame(gold_increment=9)  # if you want gold to increment by 9 each time
```

Sample game:

```
play? (Y/N)  y
Loser
play? (Y/N)  y
Loser
play? (Y/N)  y
Accumulated Gold: 2
You Win!
play? (Y/N)  y
Loser
```

Comment: Cool thanks, I was just starting with a dice simulator, so seems I ventured too far for my knowledge.  Back to learning!

Comment: np! If solution works for you, please approve. Otherwise let us know if ya need anything else.

Comment: It won't let me approve cuz I'm new or something.